# RestKit/CoreData : Not updating existing instances

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

i'm working on an IOs project, i'm using 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0rc'.

I have an issue concerning a list of objects stored in my database.

When i get from my server a new lists and i try to update the already existing one, i noticed that the objects in my the database that have a similar primary key to the objects i'm getting from my server are the ones that are not updating.

But new objects (don't already exist in database) are being added, i followed the documentation but still nothing is changing and no updates are taking place.

i'm using the : identificationAttributes = @[ @"objectId" ] so i won't have a duplicated objects.

What is the problem? in the version of Restkit?

Thank you!

Configuration Mapping Method :

```
- (void)configure
{
RKEntityMapping *storeMapping = [self mappingStore];

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:storeMapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}
```

StoreMapping :

```
- (RKEntityMapping *)mappingStore {
RKEntityMapping *storeMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Store" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[storeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:Store.mapDictionary];
storeMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"storeId" ];
return storeMapping;
}
```

Map Dictionary :

```
+(NSDictionary *)mapDictionary{
return @{
         @"id": @"storeId",
         @"name_en": @"nameEn",
         @"description_en": @"descriptionEn",
         @"address_en": @"addressEn",
         @"latitude": @"latitude",
         @"longitude": @"longitude",
         @"phone": @"phone",
         @"email": @"email",
         @"disponibility_en": @"disponibilityEn",
         @"images": @"images",
         };
}
```

Load Stores:

```
- (void)loadStores
{
[self configure];
[objectManager getObjectsAtPath:@"stores" parameters:@{} success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:Store.requestGetStoreSuccess object:mappingResult];
}
    failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:Store.requestGetStoreFailure object:operation];
        NSLog(@"________________________error?': %@", error);
}];
}
```

The Json I recieve :

```
 [
{
id: 6,
name_en: "Market Center Dubaï 0",
description_en: "Tenetur consectetur et et rerum alias iste molestiae qui excepturi architecto    aut. Ex doloremque repellat labore doloribus minima totam voluptas accusamus minima sint animi consequatur. Voluptatibus voluptatem ducimus expedita autem suscipit et provident sunt deserunt laborum omnis blanditiis est illo aut ea unde consequatur maxime. Iste molestiae sed ut est aut enim voluptas praesentium molestiae earum molestias nihil tenetur et ea error itaque nobis eius. Voluptas voluptatum est ab molestias explicabo quas modi natus tenetur consectetur consectetur veritatis omnis veritatis aut quis doloribus maxime",
address_en: "45 Reward St, 12340, Dubaï",
latitude: 25.2048493,
longitude: 55.2707828,
phone: "0011223344",
email: "contact@mail.com",
disponibility_en: "10h-18h Mon, Thu, Wed, Tue",
images: [ ]
}, ...
```

These are the Logs of CoreData and Mapping, i have in my database an object with "name_en" = "Market Center Dubai 2", i changed it to name_en" = "Market Center Dubai 2___5"n in the logs, RestKit detects that the other attributes have not changed, it writes in the logs : value is unchanged, but it detects that i changed the "name_en", still id doesn't do the update:

```
2015-01-12 16:49:40.802 Project[16928:766909] D restkit.core_data:RKFetchRequestManagedObjectCache.m:124 Found objects '(
"<Store: 0x7f889d8bd3c0> (entity: Store; id: 0xd000000000080002 <x-coredata://444E828C-7F64-4864-9EEB-09AE68872436/Store/p2> ; data: <fault>)"
)' using fetchRequest '<NSFetchRequest: 0x7f889de36700> (entity: Store; predicate: (storeId == 8); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )'


2015-01-12 16:49:40.803 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:869 Performing mapping operation: <RKMappingOperation 0x7f889c45e4f0> for 'Store' object. Mapping values from object {
    "address_ar" = "";
    "address_en" = "45 Reward St, 12342, Duba\U00ef";
    "description_ar" = "";
    "description_en" = "Reiciendis rerum praesentium omnis in explicabo doloremque eum aut enim dolores quis. Numquam vel dolorem quis tenetur ut perspiciatis reiciendis aliquam autem iure et expedita quam illo et consectetur nesciunt. Qui sed vel enim dolores ullam et rem recusandae est ut nisi numquam laudantium. Rerum inventore numquam dolores sapiente autem quo natus qui. Quia ab suscipit omnis dignissimos sunt eum nesciunt molestiae maiores est non ut. Ut voluptates minima modi delectus voluptates et rerum consectetur quis tempore sunt quaerat nam et non ut rerum dolores. Unde sed alias consectetur minima accusamus et eum mollitia mollitia expedita facilis deleniti. Animi non et repudiandae maxime ut quia voluptas possimus corrupti odit enim quia voluptas veniam labore";
    "disponibility_ar" = "";
    "disponibility_en" = "10h-18h Mon, Thu, Wed, Tue";
    email = "contact@email.com";
    id = 8;
    images =     (
    );
    latitude = "25.2048493";
    longitude = "55.2707828";
    "name_ar" = "";
    "name_en" = "Market Center Duba\U00ef 2____5";
    phone = 0011223344;
} to object <Store: 0x7f889d8bd3c0> (entity: Store; id: 0xd000000000080002 <x-coredata://444E828C-7F64-4864-9EEB-09AE68872436/Store/p2> ; data: <fault>) with object mapping (null)
2015-01-12 16:49:40.803 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:447 Found transformable value at keyPath 'address_en'. Transforming from class '__NSCFString' to 'NSString'
2015-01-12 16:49:40.804 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:462 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'address_en' to 'addressEn'
2015-01-12 16:49:40.804 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:493 Skipped mapping of attribute value from keyPath 'address_en to keyPath 'addressEn' -- value is unchanged (45 Reward St, 12342, Dubaï)
2015-01-12 16:49:40.804 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:447 Found transformable value at keyPath 'phone'. Transforming from class '__NSCFString' to 'NSString'
2015-01-12 16:49:40.804 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:462 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'phone' to 'phone'
2015-01-12 16:49:40.804 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:493 Skipped mapping of attribute value from keyPath 'phone to keyPath 'phone' -- value is unchanged (0011223344)
2015-01-12 16:49:40.804 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:447 Found transformable value at keyPath 'name_en'. Transforming from class '__NSCFString' to 'NSString'
2015-01-12 16:49:40.804 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:462 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'name_en' to 'nameEn'
2015-01-12 16:49:40.804 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:478 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'name_en' to 'nameEn'. Value: Market Center Dubaï 2____5
2015-01-12 16:49:40.805 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:447 Found transformable value at keyPath 'id'. Transforming from class '__NSCFNumber' to 'NSNumber'
2015-01-12 16:49:40.805 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:462 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'id' to 'storeId'
2015-01-12 16:49:40.805 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:493 Skipped mapping of attribute value from keyPath 'id to keyPath 'storeId' -- value is unchanged (8)
2015-01-12 16:49:40.805 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:447 Found transformable value at keyPath 'longitude'. Transforming from class '__NSCFNumber' to 'NSDecimalNumber'
2015-01-12 16:49:40.805 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:462 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'longitude' to 'longitude'
2015-01-12 16:49:40.805 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:493 Skipped mapping of attribute value from keyPath 'longitude to keyPath 'longitude' -- value is unchanged (55.2707828)
2015-01-12 16:49:40.805 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:447 Found transformable value at keyPath 'images'. Transforming from class '__NSArrayI' to 'NSArray'
2015-01-12 16:49:40.806 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:462 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'images' to 'images'
2015-01-12 16:49:40.806 Project[16928:766909] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:493 Skipped mapping of attribute value from keyPath 'images to keyPath 'images' -- value is unchanged ((
))
```

Comment: did you add a MOC cache?

Comment: I used : managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc]
                                             initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext]; i even commented this but it didn't work.

Comment: You should have that line in. You will need to give more details of your mapping and the JSON you're receiving. Trace logging should help you too.

Comment: I edited my question , sorry it took me this time, and thank you for your help.

Comment: That all looks ok. You should update to the current version of RestKit (0.23.3)

Comment: Hi again, i just updated RestKit but still it's not working :s

Comment: So you will need to turn on trace logging and see what it says about caching existing instances / finding existing items to update

Comment: Ok i'll do that and see what it will give

Comment: @Wain i have put the logs that i got and edited my Question

Comment: How do you see it not do the update then when the log says it does? How are you testing this / updating the UI?

Comment: I recovered the data from the server after I fetch the list that is stored in the database :  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Store"];
    return [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil] mutableCopy];